# jquery screen with hide/show

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to a div to be hidden it the screen size is bigger than 700px and shown only if the screen size is less than 700 px;

Here is the code i'm trying to implement with using jQuery 3

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if ((screen.width>701)) {
        $(".mobile-section").css('display', 'none'); $(".yourClass").hide();
    }elseif ((screen.width<=699))  {
        $(".mobile-section").css('display', 'block'); 
    }
});
```

It's not working --- am I doing anything wrong ??

Comment: use css media query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makes no sense really to use javscript/JQuery here if that is all you want try with CSS media queries like

```css
.mobile-section {
  display: none;
  background-color: orange;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .mobile-section {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-section">
  hello mobile section
</div>
```

[Check out this fildde and resize the viewable area](https://jsfiddle.net/w2guoogb/1/)

Comment: thanks .... this resolved my issue.. I had to add !important to the display --- works beautiful.

Comment: @TheNagaTanker if you have to add `!important` means that the element has inline-styles (can be added with js) so all `!important` does is overwriting inline styles. Do only use it if there is really no other solution. Either way, for your question and the given task it's not necessary to use javascript. If resolved please do not forget to accept the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

`width()` is a function supported by `jQuery` providing the `width` property of e.g. `document` or `window` elements. In your case it refers to the `document`.

http://api.jquery.com/width/

*An explanation of the difference between jQuery's .width() and screen.width would be good* - `screen.width` is a native DOM property and it returns the width of **the whole screen**, e.g. if you have a monitor with 1920x1200 resolution, `screen.width` will return `1920`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (($(this).width() > 701)) {
    $(".mobile-section").css('display', 'none');
    $(".yourClass").hide();
  }
  else {
    $(".mobile-section").css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

Comment: An explanation of the difference between jQuery's `.width()` and `screen.width` would be good

Comment: @developius I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use media queries, no JavaScript required.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    #hideMe{
      display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="hideMe">This should only be displayed on smaller than 700px screens</div>
```

You can read about media queries here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
// Returns width of browser viewport
$( window ).width();

// Returns width of HTML document
$( document ).width();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 701) {
        $(".mobile-section").css('display', 'none'); 
    } else if ($(window).width() <= 700)  {
        $(".mobile-section").css('display', 'block'); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width : 100px; height:100px;border:solid 1px red;" class="mobile-section">
</div>
```

Hope this helps.